# How to approach migrating web content from Joomla to Liferay?

Tags: joomla, liferay

I am starting to migrate a website based on Joomla! to Liferay. In the first phase I am looking for a best way to migrate web content. This is mostly static articles.
In the transition period both sites will operate simultaneously, so it would be good, if there was a way to automatically update Liferay with changes done on Joomla site. The articles aren't that many, so it could be done manually, however I would prefer some more programmatic method.

Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Comment: You could always export the `#__content` database table then import it to your Liferay database. There will possible have to be a few changes made to the SQL file before importing it so it runs smoothly

Answer (score 0):

For the updating you can use a content plugin with the onContentAfterSave event to trigger an update of the Liferay database. http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content